# How can i find the hostname of a particular Ip address?

Tags: ip-address

I have an ip address and i want to find the hostname and any other details.

I have used the following in windows command prompt run as administrator

```
nslookup %ipaddress%

nbtstat -A %ipaddress%
```

I can ping the address and get back a reply .

There is no output, it says My gateway cant find 
Now there are resources I have in Azure as well and i have run a query in Azure for all ip addresses and hostname and it is not there either .

How can i find the host name ?

Comment: You're trying to do [reverse DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/glossary/reverse-dns/). Not all IP addresses have DNS entries. And some IP addresses can have multiple DNS entries.

Comment: I have looked it up and it says it is Microsoft Corporation (MSFT),

Comment: so basically if a user tries to run an app on azure , it doesnt route to my service , it seems to go to the ip address above . I have checked in Azure and there are no routes defined